# Is there a way trigger "http trigger" azure function, after deploy ARM template?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have ARM who deploy kubernetes cluster and httptrigger function app. Inside httptrigger func I have client for kubernetes who do some action if I trigger this func manually, its work fine. But I need run this trigger automatically after deploy ARM was finished.

Comment: I'm not so clear about your question, so could you please describe your question more clearly. According to your current description, you just request your http trigger function by http request. Do you want to ask how to deploy your azure function by arm template ?

Comment: @HuryShen I have ARM who deploy kubernetes cluster and httptrigger function app. Inside httptrigger func I have client for kubernetes who do some action if I trigger this func manually, its work fine. But I need run this trigger automatically after deploy ARM was finished.

Comment: Sorry, but as far as I know, we can't do it.

Answer (score 2):

The HTTP request that triggers the Azure Function may be sent either by ARM itself or by whatever orchestrator you use to execute the template (e.g. Azure DevOps pipeline). Terraform can execute scripts directly; unless you really want to use ARM, it might be an option.

If you want to go with ARM, there are at least three options:

1. Make the Azure Function return an "empty" ARM template and trigger it by a request for a nested deployment template. https://blog.cloudtrooper.net/2017/04/04/run-azure-functions-from-your-quickstart-arm-templates/
2. Use [Azure Container Instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/container-instances/container-instances-quickstart-portal) to launch an instance of a container image as a stand-alone container in Azure and execute an arbitrary command inside. https://samcogan.com/run-scripts-in-arm-deployments-with-aci/
3. Use the [deployment scripts resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.resources/deploymentscripts) (Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts). It is basically built-in support for the approach using Azure Container Instances. See [the official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-script-template)  or an older article from the time the feature was still in preview that I still like: https://dev.to/omiossec/arm-template-what-s-new-for-2020-4kli#deployementsscripts-resource-provider

In any case, you will need to properly set up the dependsOn references so that the request is sent at the right time. Or better, use Bicep that mostly takes care of the dependencies implicitly, if used right.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Powershell to deploy your ARM template, you can use Powershell to trigger your azure http trigger function right after you deploy your ARM template:

`Invoke-WebRequest -Uri <function_uri> -Method POST`

Hope this helps!